# invalid architecture for binary when validating the archive

Tags: xcode5, archive, armv7, armv6

When Validating the Archive, I get the following warning:

**"This bundle is invalid. when supporting iPhone, the executable must include support for armv6 architecture, unless the UIRequireDeviceCapabilities include the 'armv7' capability."**

[image]

What is wrong with the build ? I am using XCode5 while minimum target set to 4.3

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while releasing the universal application.. Please share if you have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem, I have upgrade the deployment target to **6.0** from **4.3**

Hope this help someone else.

Comment: It is sufficient to upgrade to 5.0